# Algorithm to go from infix notation to a tree

Tags: algorithms, parsing, trees

I've been trying to figure out an algorithm to go from an infix equation to a syntax tree, like so:

`(1+3)*4+5`

```
      +
    *   5
  +   4
 1 3
```

However, I don't just want it to handle operators, I want it to handle functions with arbitrary argument numbers as well, i.e:

`max(1,3,7)*4+5`

```
      +
    *   5
 max  4
1 3 7
```

Here's the general algorithm I've come up with:

You start with the root node of the tree, containing a `null` value. You have a pointer which moves around the tree as you parse the expression, and starts pointed at the root node.

There are also some aspects of the tree I should probably clarify:

1. Inserting at a node means adding to the end of the node's children.
2. Injecting at a node means adding to a specific index in the node, and removing the node at that index and inserting it to the injected node. So, if node `A` has child `B` at index 0, and we inject node `C` at index 0, node `A` will have a child `C` which will have a child `B`.
3. Replacing at an index removes the node at that index and puts the alternate node in its stead. So if we have node `A` with child `B` at index 0, and we replace using `C` at index 0, we will have node `A` with child `C`.

Ok, so here's the algorithm so far.

---

For every token in the infix string:

- if the token is a number

  - insert it as a child of the current node
- if the token is an argument separator

  - traverse up the tree until the value of your current node is a function
- if the token is a left parenthesis

  - if the value of the current node is not a function, insert our token as a child node, and set our current node to the token's node.
- if the token is a right parenthesis

  - traverse until the current node is either a left parenthesis or a function
  - if the current node is a left parenthesis, replace it with its first child (index 0). This is equivalent to removing the parenthesis node from the tree structure, while keeping its first child intact.
  - traverse up one level, to the parent of the current node
- if the token is a function

  - insert the token as a child node of the current node, and set the current node to the newly inserted child node
- if the token is an operator

  - if the current node is not a left parenthesis or the root node

    - traverse up if

      - the current node is not at the root, *or*
      - the token is right associative and the precedence of the token is less than the precedence of the current node *or*
      - the token is left associative and the precedence of the token is less than *or equal* to the precedence of the current node
  - inject the token as a new node at the last index of the current node
  - set the current node to its newly added token child node

Once you have gone through all the tokens, return the first child of the root node.

---

Is there an existing algorithm I can check this against? Are there any obvious problems with this? Are there any particularly difficult to parse problems I can plug in using this and see if they work?

Comment: You may be interested in the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: @Ixrec I actually started out using that. However, I didn't like the fact that you had to know exactly how many arguments you are passing to a function. Shunting-yard, as described by wikipedia, simply won't work when you have variable-argument functions, unless *inside* the function you specify your argument number, like `max(1,2,3 @3)` or something. This is pretty ugly and why I moved to a syntax tree. Right now I'm calling it shunting-tree... although there is probably already a named algorithm that does this I just haven't found.

Answer (score 2):

Treat the comma as an infix operator.  Then

```
max(1,3,7)*4+5
```

becomes

```
        +
       / \
      *   5
     / \
   max  4
    |
    ,
   / \
  ,   7
 / \
1   3
```

The comma should have a lower precedence than your calculation operators (+ - * / etc.).

Comment: Ok, that's an interesting notion. Why?

Comment: Different approach - apply the function on two arguments and two arguments again.  `max(1,2,3)` gets changed to `max(1,(max(2,3))`

Comment: 1: You already have the mechanics in place for parsing binary operators. 2: Standardizes the number of children a node can have so that walking the tree is simpler.

Comment: @ MichaelT: Good idea but only works if the function composes its arguments associatively. It wouldn't work for eg. conditional( boolean, trueValue, Falsevalue ) or substring( string, count, start ) etc.

Answer (score 2):

At some point you just need to graduate to a proper parser, because there are too many things to track and too many boundary cases.  Adding function calls to the peg.js [example grammar](http://pegjs.org/online), you get.

```
primary
  = integer
  / "(" additive:additive ")" { return additive; }
  / function_call

function_call
  = [a-z]+ "(" args ")"

args
  = (additive ("," additive)*)?
```

Note this easily handles boundary cases like function calls and expressions nested within function calls:

```
max(3+4,min(6,(1+2)*3))+2
```